# Update progress of MBProgressHUD

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a scenario in which my app downloads a large chunk of data only for the first time and this happens in say `ViewController1`. I'm using a different class to download the data and another one to save the data. So my question is, how can I update the progress of `MBProgressHUD` object created in `ViewController1` to display the progress to the user?

The approach that I've adopted is to use `NSNotificationCenter` to send notifications. I'm sending notifications at the end of methods (13) in the class that saves data.

Here's what I've been doing:

```
//ViewController1.h
@interface ViewController1 ()
{
    MBProgressHUD *hud;
    float progress;
}
@end


//ViewController1.m
        - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(receiveNotification:)
                                                     name:@"downloadComplete"
                                                   object:nil];

        }
- (IBAction)sumitButtonDidClick:(id)sender {
    hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] init];
    hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminateHorizontalBar;
    hud.label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Please wait...", @"HUD preparing title");
    hud.minSize = CGSizeMake(150.f, 100.f);

        [hud showAnimated:YES];


        double delayInSeconds = 1.0;

        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
      progress = 0.0f;

        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
DownloadClass * obj1 = [[DownloadClass alloc] init];
            [obj1 downloadData];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [hud hideAnimated:YES];
});
}

- (void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification *) notification {

    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"downloadComplete"])
    {
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the download complete notification!");
        progress += 7.7f;
        //[hud setProgress:progress]; // won't work
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [MBProgressHUD HUDForView:self.view].progress = progress;


    });
    }
}
```

> Update: I'm receiving the notifications posted by the class that saves
>   data

Answer (score 1):

You have created a instance variable for `MBProgressHUD` as `MBProgressHUD *hud;` and you start progress on a `sumitButtonDidClick` method as below :

```
hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -30, 320, 768) ];
        hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminateHorizontalBar;
        hud.label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Please wait...", @"HUD preparing title");
        hud.minSize = CGSizeMake(150.f, 100.f);
        UIWindow *window=[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window];

        hud.center=window.center;

        [window addSubview:hud];

        [hud showAnimated:YES];
```

But increasing progress as Class method of `MBProgressHUD` as `[MBProgressHUD HUDForView:self.view].progress = progress;`.

**Fix for the issue is below** :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   hud.progress = progress;
});
```

if you want to hide the progress you can use

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [hud hideAnimated:YES];
    });
```

Comment: tried setting the progress as:`[hud setProgress:progress]`. But the progress won't update.

Comment: updated my answer can please to progress set in main queue

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for `MBProgressHUD` you appear to be creating the HUD incorrectly. The example they give, is as follows...

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

// Set the bar determinate mode to show task progress.
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminateHorizontalBar;
hud.label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Loading...", @"HUD loading title");

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    // Do something...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });
});
```

You are creating an instance and attaching it to `UIWindow`

Comment: this is because I need a horizontal bar. `MBProgressHUDModeDeterminateHorizontalBar`

Comment: @Prashant I've updated the example, its worth looking at the demo project

Comment: thank you. I'll give it a try. I've been trying the same thing.

Comment: The thing is when I use  `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0)` the data is saved via a background thread, which is not an intended behavior. So I'm directly `//Doing someting` and then requesting an update of the process in the `receiveNotification:` method that gets fired as and when a notification is posted.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation lists it like this:

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
hud.label.text = @"Loading";
NSProgress *progress = [self doSomethingInBackgroundCompletion:^{
    [hud hideAnimated:YES];
}];
hud.progressObject = progress;
```

You can find it here: https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD